# Nodejs DNS reverse module always return 0.0.0.0?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dns

Hi im using the below code to reverse look up hostnames from an IP address.

```
dns.reverse('172.217.25.4', (err, hostnames) => {
            console.log("hostname",hostnames)
        })
```

But no matter what ip address i use, it always return 0.0.0.0 in console log:

I have no idea what is going on. Could anyone please tell me what i did wrong?

Thank you in advance.

This is whole code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Popover } from 'antd';

const dns = require('dns');

export default class Popdomain extends Component {

    state={
        domains: [],
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.rdns(this.props.ipProp);
    }

    rdns (ip){
        dns.reverse(ip, (err, domains)=>{
            this.setState({domains:domains});
            console.log("ipProp:",ip);
            console.log("domains: ",domains);
        })
    }

    render(){

        var content = (
            <p>{this.state.domains}</p>
        );

        return(
            <Fragment>
                <Popover content={content} title="Domain">
                    {this.props.children}
                </Popover>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

In my console, it shows something like this:

```
ipProp: 129.94.110.163
domains:  0.0.0.0
ipProp: 129.94.248.108
domains:  0.0.0.0
ipProp: 129.94.213.38
domains:  0.0.0.0
```

Comment: works perfectly fine for me. May I know which nodejs version you are using?
 hostname [ 'hkg07s24-in-f4.1e100.net' ]

Comment: @ShreeramK hi im actually using requiring the 'dns' module and using the reverse function in reactjs

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting 0.0.0.0 back for all dns operations is the Node DNS module is a server-side module and ReactJS is client-side.

You either have to find a client-side library that supports DNS lookup, or make a request from React back to your server, do the DNS lookup there, and return the result.